# Method'' has no supported translation to SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I want to, in the midst of a linq to sql query where clause, check against a public int.  I am getting this error: Method 'Int32 isInDept(System.String)' has no supported translation to SQL.

Vaguely related classes (from a public static class called ad):

```
    //get AD property
    public static string GetProperty(this Principal principal, String property) {
        DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = principal.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
        if (directoryEntry.Properties.Contains(property))
            return directoryEntry.Properties[property].Value.ToString();
        else
            return String.Empty;
    }

    public static string GetDepartment(this Principal principal) {
        return principal.GetProperty("department");
    }
```

The Classes in question (from a different class):

```
    public int isInDept(string department) {
        PrincipalContext domain = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
        UserPrincipal userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domain, GetUserId());

        if (department == userPrincipal.GetDepartment()) {
            return 3;
        }
        else { return 2; }
    }

    public intranetGS.viewArticle viewArticle(int id) {
        string user = GetUserId();

        var result = ( from a in n.articles
                       join s in n.sections on a.section equals s.section_id
                       join p in n.privacies on a.privacy equals p.privacy_id
                       let iid = isInDept(s.name)
                       where (a.active == true && a.article_id == id && a.privacy < iid) ||
                       (a.active == true && a.article_id == id && a.privacy == 3 && a.author == user)
                       select new intranetGS.viewArticle {
                           articleId = a.article_id,
                           title = a.title,
                           author = a.author,
                           html = a.html,
                           section = s.name,
                           privacy = p.name,
                           dateCreated = a.date_created,
                           dateModified = a.date_modified,
                           userCreated = a.user_created,
                           userModified = a.user_modified
                       }).First();

        var nv = (from v in n.navs
                            join s in n.sections on v.section equals s.section_id
                            let iid = isInDept(s.name)
                            where (v.active == true && s.name == result.section && v.privacy  < 3) ||
                            (v.active == true && s.name == result.section && v.privacy == iid && v.user_created == user)
                            select v.html);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var r in nv) {
            sb.Append(nv);
        }

        result.articleNav = sb.ToString();

        return result;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?  If I can't do it this way, how is it suggested that it be done?

Comment: So what SQL do you expect that method to be translated into?

Comment: I want the isInDept() to be determined.  The end problem is that the privacy level could be 3 (if the user is not in a given department) or 2 (if the user is in a given department).  I suppose I don't fully understand the question.

Comment: Write out the SQL that you expect your query to be translated into.  It's that simple.  I can't see any possible way for that to happen with that code.  Clearly neither can the linq to sql query provider.

Comment: As an alternative, I suppose I could put in an argument into the viewArticle class called privacy and pass the two or three in that way.  I was just trying to do it in one fell swoop.

Comment: I get you.  So you're saying there's no way to do this in the linq to sql - I should use the alternative above?

Comment: LINQ to SQL translates the LINQ query (C# language) into SQL (SQL language). There must be a way to map every condition into SQL. There is no translation for that function.

Comment: So the alternative as passing the value as an argument would be better, yes?

Comment: @shubniggurath Figure out what information you actually want to get from the database.  Query for that information.  Then take that information and use whatever application-side operations you wish to further derive the information that you actually want.  When yo mix the two the query provider simply can't figure out what to do, so it decides to just yell at you until you figure it out.

Comment: I guess you didn't first search, or look in the "Related messages" over on the right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linq To SQL problem - has no supported translation to SQL (problem with C# property)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088823/linq-to-sql-problem-has-no-supported-translation-to-sql-problem-with-c-sharp)

Comment: I did search (elsewhere) and then look at three questions before adding this question.  They weren't the same.

Comment: @Servy is it possible to get rid of such errors by adding the desired custom function in sql server itself by using sql server clr integration feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to translate that function to `SQL`, one workaround for this is to make most of your query with linq to sql, and use Linq to Objects for the rest. It should be something like this:

```
 var query = ( from a in n.articles
                       join s in n.sections on a.section equals s.section_id
                       join p in n.privacies on a.privacy equals p.privacy_id
                       where (a.active == true && a.article_id == id)
                       select new intranetGS.viewArticle {
                           articleId = a.article_id,
                           title = a.title,
                           author = a.author,
                           html = a.html,
                           section = s.name,
                           privacy = p.name,
                           privacyId = a.privacy,
                           dateCreated = a.date_created,
                           dateModified = a.date_modified,
                           userCreated = a.user_created,
                           userModified = a.user_modified
                       }).ToList();
```

And then filter the list:

```
var result = query.Where(a => (a.privacyId < isInDept(a.section)) ||
                       (a.privacyId == 3 && a.author == user)).First();
```

Then you can do the same for the second query.