# Is there a library that can decompile a method into an Expression tree, with support for CLR 4.0?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, expression-trees

Previous questions have asked if it is possible to turn compiled delegates into expression trees, for example:

- [converting a .net Func<T> to a .net Expression<Func<T>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767733/converting-a-net-funct-to-a-net-expressionfunct)

The sane answers at the time were:

- It's possible, but very hard and there's no standard library solution.
- Use Reflector!

But fortunately there are some greatly-insane/insanely-great people out there who like reverse engineering things, and they make difficult things easy for the rest of us.

Clearly it is possible to decompile IL to C#, as Reflector does it, and so you could *in principle* instead target CLR 4.0 expression trees with support for all statement types. This is interesting because it wouldn't matter if the compiler's built-in special support for `Expression<>` lambdas is never extended to support building statement expression trees in the compiler. A library solution could fill the gap. We would then have a high-level starting point for writing aspect-like manipulations of code without having to mess with raw IL.

As noted in the answers to the above linked question, [there are some promising signs](http://evain.net/blog/articles/2009/04/22/converting-delegates-to-expression-trees) but I haven't succeeded in finding if there's been much progress since by searching.

So has anyone finished this job, or got very far with it?

**Note:** CLR 4.0 is now released.  Time for another look-see.

Comment: I guess it's a little bit too early. CLR 4.0 hasn't even been released yet. I would love to see something like that, though.

Comment: Doesn't vs2010 do something like this? I'm simply suggesting that if VS can do it there must be something in the framework / compiler tools that is capable of it, therefore ... someone has the answer.

Oh i have seen a suggestion on here somewhere (although I don't have the link to hand sorry) that there may be a way of exlpaining object definitions as XML and then using reflection to emit code for that. 

reverse of that maybe ... is there a reverse of emit in the reflection namespace somewhere maybe?

Comment: @Wardy: I don't know why you'd think that VS decompiles code. Since it includes a compiler, any code that it wants to show can be found in the original source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the response, I'm going to answer my question:

No.

Though of course if someone comes up with a better answer (or I come across one) I will update.

Answer (score 3):

I did a library that supports .NET 3.5 expression trees:
https://github.com/ashmind/expressive

I tried to do internal API so that .NET 4.0 support would not be that hard to add.
You can add or change steps in the IPipeline implementation to achieve just that.

One thing that I haven't done and that will be hard is support for loops, though.

Comment: Ever found a solution for this?