# Reverse of Expression<Func<T,TResult>>.Compile()?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda, expression-trees

Since we can:

```
Expression<Func<int, bool>> predicate = x => x > 5;
var result = Enumerable.Range(0,10).Where(predicate.Compile());
```

How can I:

```
Func<int,bool> predicate = x => x > 5;
Expression<Func<int,bool>> exp = predicate.Decompile();
```

That is, I want to get the corresponding `Expression` of the `Func`. Is it possible?

Comment: No it is not possible. No expression construction is emitted to the compiler. No alchemy here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [converting a .net Func<T> to a .net Expression<Func<T>>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767733/converting-a-net-funct-to-a-net-expressionfunct)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no magic `Decompile()` for a *delegate* instance, short of deconstructing the IL (perhaps with mono.cecil). If you want an expression tree, you'll have to *start* with an expression tree, so have `Expression<Func<int, bool>>` througout.

As an edge case, you can get *basic* method delegate information from the delegate's `.Method` (the `MethodInfo`) and `.Target` (the `arg0`) - however, for most scenarios involving a lambda or anonymous method this will point at the compiler-generate method on the capture class, so won't really help you much. It is pretty much limited to scenarios like:

```
Func<string,int> parse = int.Parse;
```

Answer (score 5):

Pass the lambda to a method that accepts an [Expression<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335710.aspx) and the C# compiler will pass you an expression tree at runtime. However this only works if you pass the lambda directly, not if you try to pass a delegate instance created from a lambda.

```
var exp = Decompile(x => x > 5);

public Expression<Func<int, bool>> Decompile(Expression<Func<int, bool>> exp)
{
    return exp;
}
```

The closest option I've found for decompiling a delegate instance is detailed in [this](http://evain.net/blog/articles/2009/04/22/converting-delegates-to-expression-trees) blog post from Jean-Baptiste Evain who works on the [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) team. He uses the excellent [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) project to decompile the IL into a custom AST, then he maps it as best as possible into LINQ expressions.

Comment: No. If you pass `x=>x>5` to `Decompile`, it will pass an `Expression`. I want to decompile a `Func<int,bool>`, without knowing it's content.

Comment: As Marc said, it's not possible. I just thought I'd post an example of the closest you could get to decompilation.

Comment: Yes, I knew you were posting an example of the closest when I saw your answer. But someone else doesn't think so, and he votes down :(

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use my library:
https://github.com/ashmind/expressive

Though it may not work as is for results of `Compile()`, since it is a `DynamicMethod` and getting IL of it is not straightforward. If you implement your own `IManagedMethod` implementation for `DynamicMethod`, though, it should just work.

I plan to implement `DynamicMethod` adapters, but do not yet know when.

Answer (score 1):

You can’t *decompile* the delegate, but you can certainly create a new expression tree that simply *calls* the delegate:

```
Func<int, bool> predicate = x => x > 5;
Expression<Func<int, bool>> exp = x => predicate(x);
```