# Can I transform a Func<T> into an Expression<T>?

Tags: c#, function, lambda, expression

I'd like to know if it's possible to make a `Func<dynamic, string>` become `Expression<Func<dynamic, string>>` ?

I have the following code in my .cshtml file (it's an example, not the whole code).

```
@Html.CreateSomeThing(
    @<text> 
        @TextBoxFor(model=> model.Id) 
        <span> some html here </span> 
        @DropDownListFor(model => model.Persons) 
    </text>);
```

In the .cs file i have the following:

```
public void CreateSomeThing<TValue>(Func<dynamic, object> description = null) { 
    //method body
}
```

What i'm trying to do is: Get all the expressions inside each `@TextBoxFor`, and `@DropDownListFor`. In this case i'd like to get the values from (`model.Id` and `model.Persons`). I know that it's possible by using `Expression<Func<dynamic,string>>` But if i try to change `Func<dynamic, object>` to `Expression<Func<dynamic, string>>` I get the error:

> Expression lambda cannot have a Body

Comment: There's some kind of HTML escaping issue going on with your code that renders it nearly unreadable.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809823/reverse-of-expressionfunct-tresult-compile

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179341/a-lambda-expression-with-a-statement-body-cannot-be-converted-to-an-expression

Comment: There was this: https://github.com/hazzik/DelegateDecompiler

Comment: It's not a duplicate of mentioned questions.

Comment: Can you please provide more specific example? How many `TextBoxFor`, `DropDownListFor`, etc do you have? What exact `CreateSomeThing` do?