# An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation

Tags: .net, dynamic, c#-4.0

I get this error if I try to pass dynamic type value into entity framework linq query.

```
dynamic sname = "suraj";    // even object, var
AppUser appUser = Ctx.AppUsers.First(u => u.Name == sname);
```

If i try to store the value first in string and use it, I get 
"object reference error".

```
var name = "suraj";
string sname = new string(((string)name).ToCharArray());

AppUser appUser = Ctx.AppUsers.First(u => u.Name == sname);
```

Comment: No, that is context of entity framework.

Comment: sorry, sname is dynamic in first case and name is dynamic in second case.

Comment: name is *not* dynamic. the "var" keyword does not make a variable dynamic, the compiler infer's the type by the right-hand side of the assignment, and gives the "var" that type.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [DLINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) which allows you to do stuff like:

```
var query =
    db.Customers.
    Where("City = @0 and Orders.Count >= @1", "London", 10).
    OrderBy("CompanyName").
    Select("new(CompanyName as Name, Phone)");
```

Note that expressions in the query are strings that could have been dynamically constructed at run-time.

The library has some very very nice goodies, including implicit conversion to Expression Trees, that you will be able to smoothly integrate into your existing expression tree.

(*DLINQ is pretty amazing when you think off how it was writting around 2006 and still is right on the front of C# technological advancements*; [Download included in the \LinqSamples\DynamicQuery directory here](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/bb894665.aspx))

Comment: I'd suggest this as the answer, since LINQ itself does not support dynamic objects in expressions (hence the error message).

Comment: I have not tried this solution yet. Even it this works, I am not much comfortable. It is like going back to old sql string (ado.net).

Comment: It will be anyway, Suraj. As long as you are using dynamic, it is an odd thing to complain about latebinding. Also, don't forget, you _only_ have to use it at the latebound step, all the rest can be strongtype like we all love to

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @Suraj's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5687426/1037948), since `dynamic` is apparently okay in a delegate (`Func`) but not an `Expression`, then you can [convert the delegate into an expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5133549/1037948):

```
dynamic config = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(configJsonString);
var typeName = config.type.ToString(); // clause expects a string, just separating it out for readability

// the guts of your clause --
// we'll turn this into an expression with o => wrapper(o)
Func<TEntity, bool> wrapper = (n => n.Name == typeName);

// wrap to expression and use as regular clause
var expectedType = repository.Where(o => wrapper(o)).FirstOrDefault();
```