# Error: An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, linq-to-entities

I use Asp.Net 4 and C#, I use EF 4.

I have this query, I receive an error:

```
 An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation
```

---

```
dynamic o = e.Item.DataItem;
var imagesContent = context.CmsImagesContents.FirstOrDefault(img => img.ContentId == o.ContentId);
```

It seems is imposible to Cast a Dynamic Type using a Lamba Expression.

How I can fix the problem, and able to use my object `o in my Lamba`? Thanks

PS:
`e.Item.DataItem` is of Type `CmsContent`
and `o.ContentId` is of type `Int`

Comment: Can you cast `e.Item.DataItem` to the type that defines the `ContentId` property?

Comment: I'm not able to do it inside the Lamba. Any idea how to make it?

Comment: `var o = (SomeType)e.Item.DataItem;` where `SomeType` is the type of object you are expecting.

Comment: You need to show us why you *have to* declare `o` as `dynamic` first.

Comment: because the source type is dynamic one

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614574/an-expression-tree-may-not-contain-a-dynamic-operation/14466282 -- better answer there

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unboxing the object will do the trick:

```
     int contentId = (int)o.ContentId;
     var image = context.CmsImagesContents.FirstOrDefault(img => img.ContentId == contentId);
```

For more info about 'boxing/unboxing' [click here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing)

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
dynamic o = e.Item.DataItem;
```

To

```
var o = (CmsContent)e.Item.DataItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing this issue in code that was not using dynamics in any obvious way. I found it was caused by the inclusion of the below reference in the class using statements. Removing it seemed to change the way the the compiler interpreted the Linq expression.

```
using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core;
```