# Building expression trees combining two functions to a composite function

Tags: c#, lambda, tree, expression, composite

I got the following:

```
 Expression<Func<double, double, double>> XTCylinderVolume =
                (r, h) => 3.14  * r * r * h;
 Expression<Func<double, double>> cubed =    (V) => V  * V * V ;
```

I can combine them to building a composite function call it `fgCompiled`.

```
 var cubedC = cubed.Compile();
 Func<double, double, double> fgComplied = (r, h) => cubedC(XTCylinderVolume.Compile()(r, h));

  fgCompiled(2,1)  
 //answer = 1981.385..;
```

How can I get an Expression fg  that is not compiled so that `fg.ToString()` would read like

```
=> (3.14 * r * r * h ) * ( 3.14 * r * r * h ) * (3.14 * r * r * h)
```

or hopefully neater but that would be a start.
Is there a way to decompiled a compiled function back to an expression?

Comment: For decompiling a compiled function, See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377635/create-expression-from-func

Comment: @Hammerstein will not produce the result that the OP wants. In fact the OP is asking for a result that does not include a Func.

Comment: There are two questions, the readable version and how to get a decompiled function back to an expression. I was just trying to help with one of them.

Comment: @Hammerstein OP already has the Expression.

Comment: You don't want to use `Expression.Compile`. You want to use `ExpressionVisitor` to replace `ExpressionParameter` with the body of the other `Expression<Func>.Body` then you want to put that all into a new `Expression.Lambda`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with parameter substitution using an expression visitor. This should tell you what you need to know: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/143096/Parameter-Substitution-within-Expression-Trees

Comment: thanx I think that will do for function composition.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to decompiled a compiled function back to an expression?

No, at least not an easy one. You would have to interprete the IL code and translate it back.

You can combine your two functions like this:

```
 var pr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(double), "r");
 var ph = Expression.Parameter(typeof(double), "h");
 Expression<Func<double, double, double>> fgCompiled =
    Expression.Lambda<Func<double, double, double>>(
        Expression.Invoke(
            cubed,
            Expression.Invoke(
                XTCylinderVolume,
                pr, ph)),
        pr, ph);
```

Which would give you something like `(r, h) => cubed (XTCylinderVolume (r, h))`.

It's not exactly what you asked, but it's functionally equivalent.

If you want to actually expand the function, it's a bit harder... You need to visit the expression tree of `cubed` and replace the parameter with the body of `XTCylinderVolume`.

It can be done by implementing an expression visitor:

```
class ParameterReplacementVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly ParameterExpression _paramToReplace;
    private readonly Expression _replacementExpression;
    public ParameterReplacementVisitor(ParameterExpression paramToReplace, Expression replacementExpression)
    {
        _paramToReplace = paramToReplace;
        _replacementExpression = replacementExpression;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        if (node == _paramToReplace)
            return _replacementExpression;
        return base.VisitParameter(node);
    }
}
```

Which you can then use like this:

```
var visitor = new ParameterReplacementVisitor(cubed.Parameters[0], XTCylinderVolume.Body);
var expandedBody = visitor.Visit(cubed.Body);

var fgCompiled = 
    Expression.Lambda<Func<double, double, double>>(
        expandedBody,
        XTCylinderVolume.Parameters);
```

Comment: thanx, looks like a very similar solution. 'ReplacementVisitor' is a less elegant word for 'Substitution'.

Comment: @GregorSchmitz, well "substitution" is more elegant than "replacement", if you wish, but it *is* a visitor...

Answer (score 0):

Using Thomas Levesque's visitor implementation, single-parameter lambda composition can be generalized.

```
public static Expression<Func<TSource, TFinal>>
  CompositeExpression<TSource, TInner, TFinal>
  (
    this Expression<Func<TInner, TFinal>> outerlambda,
    Expression<Func<TSource, TInner>> innerlambda)
{
  var visitor = new ParameterReplacementVisitor(outerlambda.Parameters[0], innerlambda.Body);
  var expandedOuter = visitor.Visit(outerlambda.Body);

  var composite =
    Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, TFinal>>(
      expandedOuter,
      innerlambda.Parameters);
  return composite;
}
```