# How can I make an Expression from a Delegate

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates, expression, expression-trees

I notice that I can do:

```
private static Func<int, int> foo = x => x + 1;
private static Expression<Func<int, int>> bar = x => x + 1;
```

But I cannot do an implicit cast:

```
private static Expression<Func<int, int>> baz = foo;  // won't compile
```

In C#, is there a way to create an Expression from a delegate (from a Func)?

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9377714/728795) what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes--my searching skills couldn't find that!  Thanks very much.