# Entity Framework Linq query not generating where clause in SQL Server when passed as a predicate

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

I've created a brand new Project in .NET Core 3.1 and a query I am creating is generating a SQL query (viewed in SQL Server Profiler) that does not contain a where clause and instead reads in the entire table. Is there a way to pass in a predicate and have that incorporated into the SQL statement that is ultimately generated?

In the below function `query1` is an `IQueryable<Balance>` and `query2` is an `IEnumerable<Balance>`:

```
    public int GetCount(Func<Balance, bool> predicate)
    {
        var query1 = (from b in _appContext.Balance
                      select b
                      );
        var query2 = query1.Where(predicate);
        var count = query2.Count();

        return count;
    }
```

Called like this:

```
    GetCount(p => p.Email == 'test@gmail.com');
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [converting a .net Func<T> to a .net Expression<Func<T>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767733/converting-a-net-funct-to-a-net-expressionfunct)

Comment: Ok... I found that answer confusing... but it did have a link in it that helped me out.

Comment: What LINQ are you using (your tags are conflicting): LINQ to SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x? I am guessing LINQ to EF Core 2.x which automatically converts to client side processing when it can't use server side.

Comment: @NetMage honestly, I don't know... how can I determine this?

Comment: Duplicate: [Create Expression from Func](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377635/create-expression-from-func)

Answer (score 0):

This answer helped me out: [Create Expression from Func](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377635/create-expression-from-func/9377714#9377714).

Basically I had to wrap the Func in an Expression as follows:

```
    public int GetCount(Expression<Func<Balance, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return = (from b in _appContext.TableName
                  select b
                  ).Where(predicate).Count();
    }
```

The same call worked:

```
    GetCount(p => p.Email == 'test@gmail.com');
```