# Logging lambda expressions

Tags: c#, lambda

```
public class Demo
{       
    public void When(Func<Person, bool> condition)
    {
        if (!condition)
        {
            Log.Info("Condition not met.");
            return;
        }

        // Do something
    }
}
```

In the `When` method, I would like to log when a predicate or `Func<bool>` returns false.  However, just logging "condition not met" doesn't give me much information.  If I call the method like so:

```
demo.When(x => x.Name == "John");
```

Is there a way to convert that expression into a readable/meaningful string for logging purposes?

Comment: Agree with @Kirk Woll below.  And assuming you don't want to change your method signature, you're likely SOL.  See related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767733/converting-a-net-funct-to-a-net-expressionfunct.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's not much useful meta data in an ordinary lambda.  You *could* use expression trees instead:

```
void When(Expression<Func<Person, bool>> condition)
{
    var person = new Person();
    if (!condition.Compile()(person))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Condition not met: " + condition);
        return;
    }
}
```

Then at the call site:

```
 When(x => false);
```

And the output will be:

> Condition not met: x => False

However, expression trees introduce a lot more overhead, and `condition.Compile` is not cheap either.  So I can't generally recommend this approach, but it will output useful info like you want.