# OrderBy is not translated into SQL when passing a selector function

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, sql-order-by, sql-server-profiler

When I execute:

```
var t = db.Table1.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

In SQL profiler, this is the translated SQL:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name]
FROM [dbo].[Table1] AS [Extent1]
ORDER BY [Extent1].[Name] ASC
```

Which is correct.

However, if I pass a selector function to OrderBy:

```
Func<Table1, string> f = x => x.Name;
var t = db.Table1.OrderBy(f).ToList();
```

The translated SQL is:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name]
FROM [dbo].[Table1] AS [Extent1]
```

The orderby is totally not translated.

What's the problem? They are the same lambda function, the only difference is in the 2nd case, it is first assigned to a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cause in a IQueryable world, you need an `Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>>` as the OrderBy's extension parameter, not a `Func<TModel, TValue>`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.orderby

Comment: Thanks. Wrapping the function with an expression solved the problem. But why there is no compile error when I pass a function to OrderBy?

Comment: Also, I know I can wrap a function with an expression like:

Expression<Func<Table1, string>> f = x => x.Name;

But if I aleady have the function variable, how can I convert it to an Expression?

Thanks

Comment: @NanLi no compile error, because IQueryable inherits from IEnumerable, which have an OrderBy method with an `Func<TModel, TValue>` parameter. For the second question, see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767733/converting-a-net-funct-to-a-net-expressionfunct

Comment: @NanLi I'm also curious : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12222006/iqueryable-orderby-with-functmodel-tvalue-whats-happening