# Does OrderBy followed by Skip and Take compile into query or run in memory?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

Say I have a query like this one:

```
var result=collection.OrderBy(orderingFunction).Skip(start).Take(length);
```

Will the whole query run on SQL server and return the result, or will it return the whole ordered table and then run `Skip` and `Take` in memory? I am concerned because I noticed that `OrderBy` returns `IOrderedEnumerable`.

How about something like this:

```
if(orderAscending)
   orderedCollection=collection.OrderBy(orderingFunction);
else
   orderedCollection=collection.OrderByDescending(orderingFunction);
var result=orderedCollection.Skip(start).Take(length);
```

Will the `Skip` and `Take` part run on Server or in memory in this case?

Comment: possible duplicate of [OrderBy is not translated into SQL when passing a selector function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210799/orderby-is-not-translated-into-sql-when-passing-a-selector-function)

Answer (score 3):

This query is translated into SQL.  An Entity Framework query such as

```
myTable.OrderBy(row => row.Id).Skip(10).Take(20);
```

Will produce SQL resembling the following:

```
SELECT TOP (20) [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id]
FROM ( SELECT [Extent1].[Id], row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Extent1].[Id] ASC) AS [row_number]
        FROM [my_table] AS [Extent1]
)  AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[row_number] > 10
ORDER BY [Extent1].[Id] ASC
```

I recommend downloading [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/), a utility that allows you to execute EF queries (and other queries), and see the results and the corresponding SQL. It is an invaluable tool in developing high-quality EF queries.

Comment: Sadly, actually no... your answer is correct in answering the question I put in title, but not correct if you looked in description of the problem. I think I'm having the problem described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210799/orderby-is-not-translated-into-sql-when-passing-a-selector-function/12214145#12214145

Comment: @m0s if your orderingFunction is not an expression then yes you have that problem and both answers did not help you :( This question is a duplicate then. Voting to close.

Comment: @usr yeah... I voted to close my question too, not sure how this works. Now only if there was a way to convert Func into Expression... Will probably have to rewrite few hundred of these by hand.

Comment: @m0s Sorry for the confusion.  What type does `orderingFunction` have?  How is it instantiated or where is passed in from?

Comment: @BenReich no problem, it is a Func<int,T> that basically maps selected sorting column index from view to corresponding entity property, which in retrospect was probably a pretty bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does translate to SQL. This is essential for paging.

You can verify this using SQL Profiler.