# Map Dynamic Linq Expression

Tags: c#, linq

```
public static IQueryable<T> FilterExact<T>(this IQueryable<T> details, int c, Func<T, int> lambda)
{
    if (c > 0)
    {
        details = details.Where(s => lambda(s).Equals(c));
    }
    return details;
}
```

The above is what I have so far. The current error exist due to linq to entity error, which can be fixed by switching it to IEnumerable, but instead, what I want is to be able to make a new linq Expression, instead of executing the function directly.

How would I go about doing this? I would prefer mapping from `Func<T, int>` to `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`.

The reason I need this is because there are a few places where code just as below exist, except the same code is copy-pasted multiple times with a different entity column associated. I want to create this as a method to prevent code duplication, but need a way to specify which column to use. (I first tried reflection, but it slowed everything down significantly.)

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchCriteria.StudyDate))
{
    if (searchCriteria.StudyDate.Contains(":"))
    {
        string[] dates = searchCriteria.StudyDate.Split(':');
        DateTime startDate;
        DateTime endDate;
        DateTime.TryParse(dates[0], out startDate);
        DateTime.TryParse(dates[1], out endDate);
        if (startDate.Year > 1 && endDate.Year > 1 && endDate > startDate)
        {
            dropChargesStudies = dropChargesStudies.Where(s => s.PERFORMED >= startDate && s.PERFORMED <= endDate);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("The study date is invalid.");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        DateTime studyDateParsed;
        DateTime.TryParse(searchCriteria.StudyDate, out studyDateParsed);
        if (studyDateParsed.Year > 1)
        {
            dropChargesStudies = dropChargesStudies.Where(s => s.PERFORMED.Value == studyDateParsed);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("The study date is invalid.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [converting a .net Func<T> to a .net Expression<Func<T>>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767733/converting-a-net-funct-to-a-net-expressionfunct)

Comment: Do you really need this? Can't you just change your method signature to receive `Expression<Func<...` as all standard `IQueryable<T>` methods do.

Comment: Yes I do. I'm trying to make something a little more complicated than above, and it will be used multiple times.

Comment: Then what are you are trying to do is wrong from the beginning. Good luck.

Comment: I have updated an example of why I need it.

Comment: @JosephWhitley Nothing about that example explains why you can't accept an expression.  If you don't accept an expression then it's simply impossible.  Period.

Comment: @Servy Could you then tell me how I should go about it?

Comment: @JosephWhitley Accept an `Expression`, rather than a delegate, as Joe Ivan said.

Comment: I would still need to map it from `Expression<Func<T, int>>` to `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`