# Get arguments from action created from lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates

How do I get the arguments 1 and 2 when I only have the Action delegate?

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Action act = () => new Program().Test(1, 2);
    }

    public void Test(int arg1, int arg2)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **cannot**. To do that, you would need an `Expression<Action>` (See [Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335710(v=vs.110).aspx) in the MSDN) and you cannot convert from an `Action` to an `Expression<Action>`, only the other direction.

[Further reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767733/converting-a-net-funct-to-a-net-expressionfunct)

Comment: That was my initial conception. I needed it for serializing the Action.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this:

```
Action<int,int> act = (a,b) => new Program().Test(a,b);
```

It could be called than as `act(1,2);`

Comment: I think the question is: given `act`, how to retrieve `1` and `2`?

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done using an `Action`, but a lambda expression can also be treated as an `Expression<Action>` and then it becomes possible.

Note that the code below only works for this kind of expression: it uses the knowledge that we have a **method call** and that we use **constants** as parameters.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var values = GetParams(() => Test(1, 2));
        foreach (var v in values)
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(v.ToString());
    }

    private object[] GetParams<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expr)
    {
        var body = (MethodCallExpression)expr.Body;
        var args = body.Arguments;
        return args.Select(p => ((ConstantExpression)p).Value).ToArray();
    }

    public int Test(int arg1, int arg2)
    {
        return arg1 + arg2;
    }
}
```