# Why can not be Func casted to Expression, but lambda can

Tags: c#, lambda, expression, func

In the example below, the same lambda can be hold as an `Expression` in `test` but it fails to compile when it comes form a `Func`:

```
Func<int> func = () => 2;
Expression test1 = (Expression<Func<int>>)(() => 2);
Expression test2 = (Expression<Func<int>>)(func); //does not compile
```

Why a lambda can be converted to an `Expression` directly, but not when it is represented as a `Func`?

Comment: It is a compiler trick. The compiler parses the lambda and converts it into an expression. It cannot do that with a delegate.

Comment: Answered over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767733

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen by now, I like your comment the most, I think it clears things up in a simple manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Func<int>` is a delegate instance - an instance of an object; it no longer has any semantic state other than "this target object reference, this method handle".

An *expression tree* is something **much richer**; it is a complex graph of the *intent* of code - essentially an AST. You can compile an expression to a delegate instance, but you cannot reverse a delegate to an expression tree.

When you do:

```cs
Expression<Func<int>> func = () => 2;
```

you are creating a complex tree; essentially:

```cs
var func = Expression.Lambda<Func<int>>(Expression.Constant(2, typeof(int)),
    Array.Empty<ParameterExpression>());
```

(but much more complex in the general case, obviously)