# IMongoCollection<T> throws an when I pass in a predicate for Func<T, bool>

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to unit-test a ASP.NET Core web controller. Here's what the naive data-access looked like:

```cs
var database = configuration.GetSection("MongoDb:Database").Value;
var mongoSettings = new MongoCollectionSettings() { AssignIdOnInsert = true };
var users = client.GetDatabase(database).GetCollection<User>("User", mongoSettings);
var user = users.Find(u => u.EmailAddress == emailAddress).SingleOrDefault();
```

This works fine. It's not easily unit-testable (`Find` is not mockable with Moq), and I would prefer a layer of indirection over my data-access, so I tried refactoring out into a repository class like so:

```cs
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    T SingleOrDefault(Func<T, bool> predicate);
}


public class MongoRepository<T> : IRepository<T>
{
    // ...
    public T SingleOrDefault(Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        var objects = client.GetDatabase(this.databaseName).GetCollection<T>(this.repositoryName, this.settings);
        var toReturn = objects.Find(o => predicate(o) == true).SingleOrDefault();
        return toReturn;
    }
}
```

When I update my controller to use `MongoRepository<User>` instead, it throws:

```cs
var usersRepo = new MongoRepository<User>(this.configuration, this.client);
var user = usersRepo.SingleOrDefault(u => u.EmailAddress == emailAddress);
```

Specifically, in the repository code, `objects.Find(o => predicate(o) == true).SingleOrDefault();` throws an exception: `An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in MongoDB.Driver.dll but was not handled in user code: 'Invoke(value(System.Func`2[AutoDungeoners.Web.Models.User,System.Boolean]), {document}) is not supported.'`

I am not sure how to resolve this. I suspect the definition of my predicate as `Func<T, bool>` is incorrect, because if I just call `objects.Find(o => true)`, it returns the first object without any issue.

Full exception stack below.

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in MongoDB.Driver.dll but was not handled in user code: 'Invoke(value(System.Func`2[AutoDungeoners.Web.Models.User,System.Boolean]), {document}) is not supported.'
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.GetFieldExpression(Expression expression)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.TranslateComparison(Expression variableExpression, ExpressionType operatorType, ConstantExpression constantExpression)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.TranslateComparison(BinaryExpression binaryExpression)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.Translate(Expression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.Translate(Expression node, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.Translate[TDocument](Expression`1 predicate, IBsonSerializer`1 parameterSerializer, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry)
   at MongoDB.Driver.ExpressionFilterDefinition`1.Render(IBsonSerializer`1 documentSerializer, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.CreateFindOperation[TProjection](FilterDefinition`1 filter, FindOptions`2 options)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.FindSync[TProjection](IClientSessionHandle session, FilterDefinition`1 filter, FindOptions`2 options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.<>c__DisplayClass41_0`1.<FindSync>b__0(IClientSessionHandle session)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.UsingImplicitSession[TResult](Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.FindSync[TProjection](FilterDefinition`1 filter, FindOptions`2 options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.FindFluent`2.ToCursor(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.IAsyncCursorSourceExtensions.SingleOrDefault[TDocument](IAsyncCursorSource`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.IFindFluentExtensions.SingleOrDefault[TDocument,TProjection](IFindFluent`2 find, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Comment: What is the type of `EmailAddress`? Just out of curiosity, what if you try simplifying to `var toReturn = objects.Find(predicate).SingleOrDefault();` I don't know how it builds queries, but I wonder if it doesn't like that you're invoking the predicate rather than just providing it as a parameter.

Comment: @ScottHannen `EmailAddress` is just a string. I think `objects.Find(predicate)` doesn't compile because it's trying to convert `System.Something.Expression<Func<User, bool>>>` to `Func<User, bool>`.

Comment: What about converting the `Func` to an Expression before you pass it in? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767733/converting-a-net-funct-to-a-net-expressionfunct

Comment: @ScottHannen that results in the same exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only implementation of `Find(...)` method you can use here is [(docs)](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/7a2af91bb400ca23e2ec8cd0d14accc7b14908fa/src/MongoDB.Driver/IMongoCollectionExtensions.cs#L877):

```
public static IFindFluent<TDocument, TDocument> Find<TDocument>(this IMongoCollection<TDocument> collection, Expression<Func<TDocument, bool>> filter, FindOptions options = null)
```

The difference between `Func` and `Expression<Func>` was described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793571/why-would-you-use-expressionfunct-rather-than-funct). Basically `GetCollection` returns a reference to Mongodb collection and the role of `Find` method here is to convert **expression tree** into MongoDB query. The moment when your query gets executed in the database is when you call `SingleOrDefault()` and this is where you're going to get an exception.

Since there's no implicit conversion between `Func<T,bool>` and `Expression<Func<T,bool>>` you tried to use `o => predicate(o) == true` which creates another expression and makes your code compileable but as mentioned - MongoDB .NET driver will not be able to figure out how to translate such expression into MongoDB query.

You need to change your implementation into:

```
public T SingleOrDefault(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    var objects = client.GetDatabase(this.databaseName).GetCollection<T>(this.repositoryName, this.settings);
    var toReturn = objects.Find(predicate).SingleOrDefault();
    return toReturn;
}
```

And keep in mind that this will work only for those expression that can be translated into MongoDB query language. `u => u.EmailAddress == emailAddress` looks fine.

Comment: Your explanation makes sense. Aside from the problem of having to pass in a `Func` instead of a predicate, this code doesn't compile - `predicate(o)` doesn't work for `Func`. Also, see Scott's comments above: converting to an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` throws the same exception.

Comment: @nightblade9 that's my bad, sorry - don't run the predicate just pass the expression. Modified my answer

Comment: Whoa that actually works! I'm a bit surprised (I was doing something similar based on the comments - just internally converting `Func<T, bool>` to `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` and it throws). Thanks so much for this!